# How to scrape numbers after clicking buttons on multiple pages?

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

Previously i asked how to click a button on page. And it worked first time, but i realized that sometimes it works sometimes it doesn't. Problem is i have multiple pages, and sometimes i get numbers for some pages, but for some i get nothing. Is there any way to get all data that i need? Project is my final exam in this beginers course in Python.

The buttons that need to be clicked are on top right side of the page and it shows text "Prikaži broj".
This is my try but it isn't working as i want:

```
condos = [
'https://www.nekretnine.rs/stambeni-objekti/stanovi/vracar-lokacija-juzni-bulevar-adresa-vojvode-hrvoja-beograd/1958955/',
'https://www.nekretnine.rs/stambeni-objekti/stanovi/vozdovac-autokomanda-trise-kaclerovica-90m2-trise-kaclerovica/NkvU3_gZyb6/',
'https://www.nekretnine.rs/stambeni-objekti/stanovi/vracar-prote-mateje-78m2-id1187/NkwQVDgJqsw/',
'https://www.nekretnine.rs/stambeni-objekti/stanovi/palilula-botanicka-basta-bulevar-despota-stefana-60m2-bulevar-despota-stefana/1734451/',
'https://www.nekretnine.rs/stambeni-objekti/stanovi/palilula-postanska-stedionica-dalmatinska-94m2-dalmatinska/Nk1bTYWifZj/',
'https://www.nekretnine.rs/stambeni-objekti/stanovi/stari-grad-kalemegdan-strahinjica-bana-37m2-strahinjica-bana/NklcRCutVNB/',
'https://www.nekretnine.rs/stambeni-objekti/stanovi/palilula-borca-moravske-divizije-73m2-moravske-divizije/207667/',
'https://www.nekretnine.rs/stambeni-objekti/stanovi/palilula-visnjicka-banja-slobodana-jovanovica-75m2-slobodana-jovanovica/Nk2nu-zdbzW/',
'https://www.nekretnine.rs/stambeni-objekti/stanovi/zvezdara-mirijevo-jovanke-radakovic-61m2-jovanke-radakovic/NkW5Qg22seE/',
'https://www.nekretnine.rs/stambeni-objekti/stanovi/zvezdara-deram-pijaca-duke-dinic-80m2-duke-dinic/Nk26as4b71N/']

condo_agency_home_phones = []
condo_agency_cell_phones = []

options = Options()
options.headless = False
driver = webdriver.Chrome('/Users/Nenad/chromedriver', options=options)
for condo in condos:
    driver.get(condo)
    try:
        element = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('body > div:nth-child(14) > div.row.pt-4 > div.col-lg-4.mb-5 > div.border-box.pt-3.pl-3.pr-3.pb-0.d-none.d-lg-block > div > div.row > div.col-12.col-sm-6.contact-footer > div > div > form:nth-child(2) > button').click()
        sleep(randint(3, 5))
        element2 = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('body > div:nth-child(14) > div.row.pt-4 > div.col-lg-4.mb-5 > div.border-box.pt-3.pl-3.pr-3.pb-0.d-none.d-lg-block > div > div.row > div.col-12.col-sm-6.contact-footer > div > div > form:nth-child(4) > button').click()
        sleep(randint(3, 5))
        home_phone = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('body > div:nth-child(14) > div.row.pt-4 > div.col-lg-4.mb-5 > div.border-box.pt-3.pl-3.pr-3.pb-0.d-none.d-lg-block > div > div.row > div.col-12.col-sm-6.contact-footer > div > div > form:nth-child(2) > span')
        cell_phone = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('body > div:nth-child(14) > div.row.pt-4 > div.col-lg-4.mb-5 > div.border-box.pt-3.pl-3.pr-3.pb-0.d-none.d-lg-block > div > div.row > div.col-12.col-sm-6.contact-footer > div > div > form:nth-child(4) > span')
        condo_agency_home_phones.append(home_phone.text)
        condo_agency_cell_phones.append(cell_phone.text)
    except:
        condo_agency_home_phones.append('NaN')
        condo_agency_cell_phones.append('NaN')
```

Solution that i got was:

```
element = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('button[type="button"]').click()
```

This click on button sometimes, and i still don't know how to extract number after click.
If anyone knows how to do it, please tell me.

Comment: If the number is present on the page, you should be able to get it by calling `driver.find_element_by_id` (or `by_xpath`, or `by_css_selector`, etc.)  Did you try doing that?

Comment: It shows after click. Problem is it doesn't click every time and i cannot get number then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `WebDriverWait` to handle dynamic element.However you need give some time.sleep(1) after clicking on the button to get entire phone number.

```
condo_agency_home_phones = []
condo_agency_cell_phones = []
 for condo in condos:
        driver.get(condo)

        try:
            wait=WebDriverWait(driver,10)
            element =wait.until(expected_conditions.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//button[contains(text(),'broj')]")))
            element.click()
            time.sleep(1)
            home_phone=wait.until(expected_conditions.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"(//span[@class='cell-number'])[1]")))
            condo_agency_home_phones.append(home_phone.text)

            wait1 = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
            element2 =wait1.until(expected_conditions.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//button[contains(text(),'broj')]")))
            element2.click()
            time.sleep(1)
            wait2 = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
            cell_phone=wait2.until(expected_conditions.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"(//span[@class='cell-number'])[2]")))
            condo_agency_cell_phones.append(cell_phone.text)
        except:
            condo_agency_home_phones.append('NaN')
            condo_agency_cell_phones.append('NaN')

    print(condo_agency_home_phones,condo_agency_cell_phones)
```

Please note you need to use following imports.

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions
from selenium import webdriver
import time
```

Comment: This code is correct! Just one thing, it appears that whenever advertisement loads with page, for that page i don't get phone numbers. Is there a way to load adblock in webdriver?

Comment: I have to check and let you know tommow.is that fine? Can accept my answer if it helps.

Comment: No problem. At least you helped me a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to SO.
Here are the options.

Option1 : Using Expected Conditions (by this way you are making sure the element is located before clicking)

```
wait = WebDriverWait(self.driver, 10)
ele = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//button[.='Prikaži broj']")))
ele.click
```

Option 2: Using Java script. (This like dispatching click event on the button)

```
ele = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[.='Prikaži broj']")
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();",ele);
```

Answer (score 0):

You might also consider trying a wait for clickable

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "form button[type=button]"))).click()
```

Additional imports:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

Answer (score 0):

The following code involve Adblock and with it i get most of time all numbers:

```
path_to_extension = r'C:\Users\Nenad\Desktop\3.42.0_0'
options = Options()
options.add_argument('load-extension=' + path_to_extension)
options.headless = False
driver = webdriver.Chrome('/Users/Nenad/chromedriver', options=options)
driver.create_options()
```

The path for extension is copied from:

C:\Users\Nenad\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Extensions\gighmmpiobklfepjocnamgkkbiglidom

I think this is working solution.